# Amazon SageMaker Model Monitor for Batch Transform jobs

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Couldn't find the right place to ask this, so doing it here.

Does Model Monitor support monitoring Batch Transform jobs, or only endpoints? The documentation seems to only reference endpoints...

Comment: It's not supported with batch transform jobs automatically, but you can implement it manually https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-byoc-containers.html

Answer (score 1):

We just launched the support.

Here are the sample notebook:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/sagemaker_model_monitor/model_monitor_batch_transform

Here is the what's new post:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/10/amazon-sagemaker-model-monitor-batch-transform-jobs/

Comment: Who is that "We"?

Comment: This is _borderline_ link-only.  It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link(s) for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.